# Calculating the DC motor parameters from motor specifications

Tags: dc-motor, simulink

I am struggling with series DC motor modelling to study the effect of a feedback control system on its performance. Is there any method to calculate the parameters i.e. terminal inductance and resistance, inertia, and damping constants based on this DC motor spec sheet?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this might help](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/ab-025-using-spice-to-model-dc-motors/).

Comment: Could just measure them. https://support.controltechnologycorp.com/customer/elearning/younkin/motorParameters.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You need the full data sheet from the manufacturer, that in your post is only the shortform data sheet, the subset of data that most people need. You may have trouble with contacting them, given the Chinese characters on the data sheet.

You could get your simulation going by guessing at something plausible, like a several millisecond time constant with the resistance. Run your simulation with this value, then 0.1 and 10x the value, to see whether the exact value causes significant changes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

With so little data it is impossible. You can calculate the torque constant kt (or ki) [Nm/A]. Inertia can't be calculated from electrical properties.

However you could lock the rotor apply a voltage and measure current, stall current. There is a data on the picture, but without a voltage. Probably it's 3V -> R=3/4.7=0.64 Ohm. With this measurement you get resistance.

With a scope you can apply step voltage and measure current, then you get inductance.

Comment: well based on my model it seems that the simulation won't run without stating the inductance value ...